# c++ transform with if_then_else control structure

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I'm trying to change the integer values in a vector using transform and an if_then_else control structure from Boost Lambda. However my compiler is not appreciating my efforts. The code I am attempting is:

```
transform(theVec.begin(), theVec.end(), theVec.begin(), 
          if_then_else(bind(rand) % ratio == 0, _1 = bind(rand) % maxSize, _1));
```

I tried simplifying it to the following:

```
transform(theVec.begin(), theVec.end(), theVec.begin(),
          if_then_else(0 == 0, _1 = MaxIntSizeCFG, _1));
```

but the compiler tells me: no matching function for call to 'if_then_else(..........'
I read that the return values from control structures is void, so is my attempted usage in this case entirely wrong?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if_then_else` in your usage is incorrect, in the same way this is:

```
int i = if (some_condition){ 0; } else { 1; };
```

What you want is merely the ternary operator; however, this won't work in a lambda. You can simulate this with the the `if_then_else_return` structure instead. (i.e., you were close!)

The `if_then_else` is for something like a `for_each` loop, where you'd take one action or the other depending on a condition. The `if_then_else_return` is for a ternary conditional.

Comment: Ah yes of course nothing is being passed back with the if_the_else structure. I tried:

transform(theVec.begin(), theVec.end(), theVec.begin(), 
          if_then_else_return(bind(rand) % ratio == 0, _1 = bind(rand) % maxSize, _1));

and this worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: No problems, I'll be waiting for your next lambda question. :P

Comment: Haha, its queuing up! Actually can you recommend a good resource for lambada expression? I've only just started using them (as you can tell) and I'm well impressed by what can be done.

Comment: @Demps: I can't recommend more than the Boost lambda reference, unfortunately. In honestly, be careful. Lambda's are cool and easy to over-use. If you're using Boost, I recommend for-each most of the time. Lambda's are good when you really need a functor, foreach is good when you really want to loop over some elements.

Comment: Flying through boost::lambda (learnt it in two minutes - not reaaly possible in fact) to adapt back some c++11 back to non-c++11, if_then_else_return clarified an unreadable template compile error - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use Boost I recommend BOOST_FOREACH instead of such a complex lambda expression:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(int & i, v)
    i = rand() % ratio ? i : rand();
```

This will be very easy to adapt once the new range-based for loop becomes available:

```
for(int & i : v)
    i = rand() % ratio ? i : rand();
```

Comment: are there already compilers which allow the second syntax for experimental usage?

Comment: @rjones - Concept GCC supports it since 2007 (!) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2196.html. Major compilers are are taking longer because of the removal of concepts from the upcoming standard